# Implementing multiple filters on same dataset in d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, leaflet

I was hoping to get some advice on how to implement multiple range-slider filters on the same data set (but two different attributes) on a d3/leaflet map I have.

I'd like to be able to use a range-slider to filter points on the map by date, and another range-slider to filter points on the map by "size".  Currently, the way I have this set up is only meant to work for filtering by date.  Essentially, when the time-slider is instantiated, it passes in an opacity value from a function which can dynamically set the point's opacity to zero, thus filtering them out.  Here's the basic code:

```
//Build time-slider in HTML
<div  id="sliderContainer"> 
<input id="timeslide-leaflet" type="range" min="0" max="25" value="0" step="1" /><br>

//Define years for time slider
var inputValue = null;
var years = ["1993","1994","","","" ];

        //load in data
        SFData.forEach(function(d) {
        var coords = d.geometry.coordinates
        console.log(coords)
        d.latLong = new L.LatLng(coords[1],
                                coords[0]);

    })

    //draw map circles
    var feature = mapG.selectAll("circle")
        .data(SFData)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", 'features')

    //if time-slider moved, call update function
    d3.select("#timeslide-leaflet").on("input", function() {        
        update(+this.value);   
    });

    //Update function sets feature's opacity and can filter by making invisible
    function update(value) {
        document.getElementById("range-leaflet").innerHTML=years[value];
        inputValue = years[value];

        d3.selectAll(".features")
            .attr("opacity", dateMatch)       
}


    function dateMatch(data, value) {

    //do some internal calculations based on my data

    if (yearInt <= inputValueInt && yearExpirationInt >= inputValueInt) {

        return ".7";
    } else {
        return "0"; //return opacity 0 for data that should be filtered out 
    };
}
```

I would like to be able to filter the same data on a different attribute (size) in a similar way.  I can easily create another time slider - but how would I go about passing in another returned opacity value to the map features .attr("opacity")?  Essentially I could write a similar function to dateMatch() that filters by size, I'm not sure how I would pass a returned opacity value back to the map features, since dateMatch() is already passing in a value.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make a function that chains the opacity

```
d3.selectAll(".features")
    .attr("opacity", calcOpacity);

function calcOpacity(d) {
    var opacity = dateOpacity(d, 1);
    return c2Opacity(d, opacity);
}

function dateOpacity(d, opacity) {
    if (opacity === 0.0) return opacity;
    // calcs
    return (yearInt <= inputValueInt && yearExpirationInt >= inputValueInt) ? 0.7 : 0.0;
}

function c2Opacity(d, opacity) {
    if (opacity === 0.0) return opacity;
    // calcs
    return Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0.7 : 0.0;
}
```

**Edit**

I have removed DiamondJoe12 edit of this answer and put in place a snippet that use 2 sliders to filter the circles in the chart.

The slider supply the `year` and `size` value that is needed, I don't see a reason to use a lookup array.

The lowest value of the slider is used as a sentinel to pass all on that particular filter.

The snippet show an svg with 500 circles of different sizes and different year data.

```js
var svgWidth = 500, svgHeight = 500;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", svgWidth)
    .attr("height", svgHeight);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([-0.1, 1.1]).range([0, svgWidth]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([-0.1, 1.1]).range([0, svgHeight]);

var data = d3.range(500).map(i => ({x:Math.random(), y:Math.random(),
    year: 1993 + Math.floor(Math.random()*26),
    size: 4 + Math.floor(Math.random()*7) }));

svg.selectAll(".features")
    .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "features")
    .attr("cx", d => x(d.x))
    .attr("cy", d => y(d.y))
    .attr("r", d => d.size)
    .attr("fill", (d, i) => color(i));

//if time-slider moved, call update function
d3.select("#timeslide-leaflet").on("input", function() {
    update();
});

d3.select("#sizeslide-leaflet").on("input", function() {
    update();
});

update();

//Update function sets feature's opacity and can filter by making invisible
function update() {
    var year = +document.getElementById("timeslide-leaflet").value;
    year = year === 1992 ? 0 : year;
    document.getElementById("time-leaflet").innerHTML = year === 0 ? "All" : year;

    var size = +document.getElementById("sizeslide-leaflet").value;
    size = size === 3 ? 0 : size;
    document.getElementById("size-leaflet").innerHTML = size === 0 ? "All" : size;

    svg.selectAll(".features")
      .transition()
      .duration(200)
        .attr("opacity", d => calcOpacity(d, year, size) );
}

function calcOpacity(d, year, size) {
    var opacity = dateOpacity(d, year, 1);
    return sizeOpacity(d, size, opacity);
}

function dateOpacity(d, year, opacity) {
    if (opacity === 0.0) return opacity;
    if (year === 0)  return opacity; // All pass
    return (d.year === year) ? 0.7 : 0.0;
}

function sizeOpacity(d, size, opacity) {
    if (opacity === 0.0) return opacity;
    if (size === 0)  return opacity; // All pass
    return d.size === size ? 0.7 : 0.0;
}
```

```css
.features {
stroke:black;
stroke-width:0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="sliderContainer"> 
<input id="timeslide-leaflet" type="range" min="1992" max="2018" value="1992" step="1" /><br/>
<input id="sizeslide-leaflet" type="range" min="3" max="10" value="3" step="1" />
</div>
<div>
<div>Year: <span id="time-leaflet"></span></div>
<div>Size: <span id="size-leaflet"></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer here.  Not sure why it was down-voted. While I think I see the logic here, I ended up implementing a less efficient but more straightforward approach.. it's a lot of duplicated code but it works.  I essentially just duplicated the slider, and added conditions so that if the 'size' AND the 'date' conditions are met with the size-slider, it will adjust opacity accordingly.  That way, the date and time slider are working in conjunction and I can filter size/date simultaneously.

Comment: @DiamondJoe12: if you read the value of both sliders in the update functin and call the update function on change of both sliders it doesn't need duplication of code

Comment: rio- see above.  I'm following your suggestion - but I can't seem to pass in the value of both sliders in the d3.select().on("input()) function I've shown above.  I think I'm close but there's still something i'm not doing right.

Comment: @DiamondJoe12: have a look at the example